# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '!' - error caught by Sentry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js, sentry

The error in the title is caught by Sentry (an error tracking tool). Below is a screenshot from Sentry - showing the stack trace.

[image: sentry screenshot]

Note: the script `/en_US/iab.autofill.payment.js` where `handleMessage` is located is loaded from Facebook ([link here](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/iab.autofill.payment.js)), and I couldn't find this script in the javascript bundle, nor anything related to it. I assume it's loaded by a 3rd party script - I'm using Google Tag Manager (which is also loading Facebook Pixel), Segment (loading Hotjar and Mixpanel), and Snapchat. The error started to appear without any changes in these scripts or the services that they're sending data to.

Note 2: It seems that the error is triggered quite often, about 10-15% of the time. I tried to reproduce it but given that it's a `handled` error, it doesn't show in the dev console.

Any direction on where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: it all comes down to not all messages being in the valid json format (the only place where the function is called is inside of the message event listener)

Comment: `console.log(e.data);` right above line 178. This may reveal where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @LonnieBest the script is hosted by Facebook - I can't alter it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue went away after a couple of weeks without changing anything on my side.

Comment: strangely though, i started to see this issue on my sentry from Oct 28, really within just 4 days i have 2.1k instances of these errors. any clue how u handled it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing this a lot, and it seems to be coming 100% from users using Facebook browser on iOS (I guess this is the browser you see when you're using the Facebook app).

I tried to debug this with a snippet:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('foo');
    }, false);
</script>
```

This is from the library you linked. Assuming that e.data is JSON string (not e.g. an object?), without any safeguard seems to be breaking things.

The second console.log doesn't fire, so I think this is causing some unexpected behaviours in my case (buttons not reacting to clicks with js listeners etc)

I don't know if there is a workaround or a way to protect from this in Facebook embedded browser (I guess it's loaded there)

Looking forward to hear more info

Comment: Thanks, Zoran! Seems a good place to start. But given it is on iOS, do you have any recommendation on how I could actually see the browser's logs? - given the script is running in the browser. Dev console on macOS can be linked only to mobile safari as far as I know, not having the option to do the same on the Facebook browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still fighting with this issue too. I can't find a way to properly debug it, Facebook's in-app browser is garbage :D My team and I tried to reproduce this on various iOS devices through the In-app browser, but features are working and no logs are recorded in Sentry for our sessions. 

IDK if there's anything we can do except reporting this somewhere to Facebook's team and hope for a timely reaction :/

Answer (score 0):

i have meet that too, its because the one script facebook inject in. will postMessage(Object), but the another script will listen the message and try to JSON.parse an object ,so it will came out a error. u can use 'vconsole' lib, and  add a `window.addEventListener('message',(e)=>{console.log(e.data)})` and u can see that